# If page is not index/ homepage then do this in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a website for a client who doesn't want me to put "Web Development by ..." on the homepage but only not the homepage, he doesn't have any complaints about finding it on all inner pages.

I am trying that if the URL is not homepage (example.com/ ) he will populate div with my text.

And I really don't now how to do this, I couldn't find anything on web (maybe my poor English).

Comment: so ... only load the JS on the homepage ... or check `window.location`

Comment: Thanks for reply. What i am trying is to JS recognize innerpage like /about-us or /news-03-02-2017 and then load. But if the url is example.com it doesnt load

Comment: I can't tell when it should or shouldn't load ... just check [window.location]

Comment: check window.location.href and find last position of " / " if  it is more than 7 then its not your homepage

Comment: The duplicate is for client side scripting. For PHP, you know what page you are on